# How to integrate Custom ad mechanism in android application?

Tags: android, admob, ads, mopub

I want my android application to continuously run a service in background which should start a full screen activity (something like Interstitial Ad) after specific time intervals (say 5 mins). I want to manage these ads too (Custom banners totally designed by me) and need the statistical data about clicks etc. I've no prior experience in Ads integration and management. Do i have to use my own server backend to download ads from, in app or is there any framework which can allow me to push/show my own ads along with Admin Dashboard for reporting (Admob/Airpush/Mopub anything ? ). There is too much business jargons on official sites and i need some plain simple solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you find any easy solution?